# Setting custom header using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, rest, http-headers, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I am simply making a `GET` request to a Rest API using `HttpURLConnection`.

I need to add some custom headers but I am getting `null` while trying to retrieve their values.

**Code:**

```
URL url;
try {
    url = new URL("http://www.example.com/rest/");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Set Headers
    conn.setRequestProperty("CustomHeader", "someValue");
    conn.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");

    // Output is null here <--------
    System.out.println(conn.getHeaderField("CustomHeader"));

    // Request not successful
    if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Request Failed. HTTP Error Code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
    }

    // Read response
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    StringBuffer jsonString = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        jsonString.append(line);
    }
    br.close();
    conn.disconnect();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: this returns your value;  System.out.println(conn.getRequestProperty("CustomHeader"));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `conn.getHeaderField("CustomHeader")` returns the *response* header not the request one.

To return the request header use: `conn.getRequestProperty("CustomHeader")`

Comment: Yeah, it returned that. Thanks :)
Not sure then why getting 401.

Answer (score 12):

It is a good idea to send

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("CustomHeader", token);
```

instead of

```
// Set Headers
conn.setRequestProperty("CustomHeader", "someValue");
conn.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");
```

Both the type value and header should be changed. 
it works in my case.

Comment: It's a `GET` request. I am not sending any content & expecting the response of type `application/json` so, is there any reason for using `Content-Type` instead of `accept` here?

Comment: Who took it upon themselves to rename "header" to "property" ? This was very surprising.